# Is the SEE INVISIBLE intrinsic gained from quaffing from a fountain permanent?

Tags: nethack

I looked in the wiki about this but it doesn't say whether it's permanent or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is permanent, unless stolen by a [gremlin](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gremlin).